# Pagination in jquery is jumping back to first page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination

I have created a jquery pagination but the problem is, after I perform editing or deletion of the entries in database that are shown in the pagination list. The pagination gets refreshed and jumps back to the first page. I want to get back to the same page after I perform editing or deletion in a page.

I am using the following code in a file called `list.php`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php"); //initial page number to load
    $(".pagination").bootpag({
        total: <? php echo $pages; ?> ,
        page: 1,
        maxVisible: 5
    }).on("page", function (e, num) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');
        $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {
            'page': num
        });
    });
});
```

and in a file called `fetch_pages.php` I'm using the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST["page"])){

    $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
        die('Invalid page number!');
     } //incase of invalid page number
     echo "$page_number";  
}else{
    $page_number = 1;        
}

//get current starting point of records
$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT id, seae, brand, territory, name, e_id, email, contact ,exist FROM employees ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");
```

`$position` stores the value that defines number of records that need to be displayed on the page.
Can anyone help me on how to get back to the same page without getting back to the first page?

Comment: how do you perform edit / delete ? 
does the page refresh by edit /delete ?

Comment: @sarath i have added up two buttons for the deletion and edit in the page where the list is displayed with pagination clicking on that will redirects to the respective page and after once the task is done the page is redirected back to this list.php which displays the list. yes the page is being refreshed

Comment: refreshing resets the variables to initial status...
so you may need to ajax to perform edit / delete...
or you could keep track last page ( $position ) in a session variable...

$_SESSION['position']=$position;
$position=isset($_SESSION['position'])?$_SESSION['position']:(($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);

Comment: @sarath how can i do that please don't mind i am little noob in this can you explain me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php"); //initial page number to load
    $(".pagination").bootpag({
        total: <? php echo $pages; ?> ,
        page: <?=$_SESSION['position']?$_SESSION['position']:1?>,
        maxVisible: 5
    }).on("page", function (e, num) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');
        $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {
            'page': num
        });
    });
});


if(isset($_POST["page"])){

    $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
        die('Invalid page number!');
     } //incase of invalid page number
     echo "$page_number";  
}else{
    $page_number = 1;        
}

//get current starting point of records
$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
$_SESSION['position']=$position;
```

you need to reset $_SESSION['position'] to start from first

Comment: Now after the changes are done the pagination and the list is not showing up at all. what might be wrong>

Comment: there is another line which retrieves data from the database do i need to change anything in this   $results = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT id, seae, brand, territory, name, e_id, email, contact ,exist FROM employees ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");

Comment: no.. nothing need to do with that... did you tried inspect on browser whether the ajax call makes any error... 
another possibility is you may not put session_start() on the page starts....

Comment: i have put session_start and everything seems fine but i am not getting why its not displaying the pagination list